# R ggplot how to manually change legend name and colors

Tags: r, ggplot2

I having trouble changing the colors and labels of my chart. I want to use scale_color_discrete to change the order and names of the legend and use scale_color_manual to change the colors of the graph. However, these appear to overlap each other and the graph goes back to the default colors or will use my colors but not change the labels. The error message is: "Scale for 'colour' is already present. Adding another scale for 'colour', which will replace the existing scale."

How can I change but the labels and colors?

Here is my code and the picture of the graph: [image: Chart]

```
ggplot(model_set2, aes(x = mon.sst.levels, y = count.inv, shape = year_bin, color = mon.sst.levels)) +
  geom_point(position ="jitter", alpha = 0.7, size = 2) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("low", "med", "high"), labels= c("Low", "Medium", "High")) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(500, 1000)) +
  xlab("Average Monthly SST") +
  ylab("Count of Individals") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#5436D9", "#D93840", "#55F2BB")) +
  scale_shape_discrete(name = "Years") + 
  scale_color_discrete(name = "SST Levels", limits = c("low", "med", "high"), labels= c("Low", "Medium", "High")) +
  ggtitle("Population Size due to SST") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 18, face = "bold")) +
  theme_bw()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using a dataset included with ggplot2.

You should only have one scale for each aesthetic. You can define the name, the breaks, and the colors like below:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = cut, y = price, shape = color, color = clarity)) +
  geom_point(position ="jitter", alpha = 0.7, size = 2) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "SST Levels", 
                     values = c("I1" = "#5436D9", "SI2" = "#D93840", "SI1" = "#55F2BB",
                                "VS2" = "#5436D9", "VS1" = "#D93840", "VVS2" = "#55F2BB",
                                "VVS1" = "#BBBBBB", "IF" = "#445599")) +
  scale_shape_discrete(name = "color")
```

[image]